# Derivation of particle distribution in a gravitational field

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, molecules

I'm trying to figure out where my logic is failing in the derivation of the concentation of particles with respect to the height in constant temperature and gravity ($n(h)$).

So we have the following equations:
$$p=\rho gh=mn(h)gh \\
  p=n(h)kT$$
If we differentiate both of those with respect to h we get:
$$\frac{dp}{dh}=mg(h\frac{dn}{dh}+n)\\
   \frac{dp}{dh}=kT\frac{dn}{dh}$$ So we get to this differential equation:
$$\frac{dn}{dh}kT=mg(h\frac{dn}{dh}+n)$$ which when solved gives us the solution:
$$n(h)=\frac{c}{kT-mgh}$$ And this is way different than the actual answer:
$$n(h)=n_0e^{-\frac{mgh}{kT}}$$
I understand that if in the first equation I treat n as a constant I will get the right answer but why should I do that? I dont see where is the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation is wrong. $P = \rho g h$ is true only when the density is the same. A proper way to derive is by noting that

$$ \frac{dP}{dh} = -\rho g$$

where this equation holds true for all static fluids that stay at rest under gravity. This can be derived by using newton's laws for a static slab of fluid suspended on air. Now if we assume that the gas is ideal, we can use $P = nk_BT$. Also assuming the gas is monoatomic we have

$$ \frac{dn}{dh} = -\frac{m g}{k_B T} n$$

You can then integrate this equation easily to get your answer.